# Sending commands across VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cross-platform, coreldraw

I am writing a script in VBA that creates a drawing in CorelDraw. I am having trouble centering the text. Here is the code that works properly in CorelDraw's Macro editor:

```
Dim s2 As Object
    Dim Txt As Object
    Dim test As String
    Dim returntest As String
    returntest = "Test~Test1234~Test56~Test789"
    test = Replace(returntest, "~", Chr(13))
    Set s2 = CorelApp.ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(-7.75, (1 - 0.5) / 2, test)
    Set Txt = s2.Text
    Txt.Story.Font = "Swis721 BT"
    Txt.Story.Size = 20
    Txt.Story.LineSpacing = 75
    Txt.Story.Alignment = cdrCenterAlignment
    s2.Fill.UniformColor.CMYKAssign 0, 0, 0, 100
    s2.Outline.SetNoOutline
    s2.CenterX = s1.CenterX
    s2.CenterY = s1.CenterY
```

s1 is simply a rectangle that is already defined. The problem is with "cdrCenterAlignment". VBA does not recognize it as a valid argument because it is referencing something that exists only within CorelDraw. I get "cdrCenterAlignment variable not defined" or "type mismatch" if I call it a string. **How, if even possible, can I send this command/argument to CorelDraw while still working in Excel?**

I ran into similar problems sending the same drawing to AutoCAD but was able to work around it by sending things to the Command line.

Comment: Is Corel library linked to Excel VBA Project (via Tools -> References)?

Comment: ^^ that. Reference the CorelDRAW library and the constants will be defined, and you can use actual CorelDRAW types and API and enjoy IntelliSense and auto-complete, instead of working against the `Object` interface and constantly referring to documentation for what members are available on what objects - and dealing with run-time error 438 whenever you make a typo, because late-bound code will happily compile and only be resolved at run-time.

Comment: I did not link them because I do not know how that link will transfer if I send the document to a different computer. Does the link remain, or will it have to be re-linked any time it is sent to a different computer?

Comment: The "link" is stored in the project's references, saved along with the VBA project inside the host Office document. There is no reason whatsoever to stick to late binding if all your users have all the same versions of the libraries you're referencing. And if a user doesn't have a library you're late-binding to, your program is going to crash anyway... the difference is whether you want your program to blow up at compile-time (early), or at run-time (late), and whether you care for IntelliSense/autocomplete as you build your thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VBA code you can define it yourself:

```
Const cdrCenterAlignment = 3
```

https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/19/e/cdrAlignment

Comment: Thank you, that site is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Reference the CorelDRAW library (Tools > References) and the constants will be defined, and you can use actual CorelDRAW types and API and enjoy IntelliSense and auto-complete, instead of working against the `Object` interface and constantly referring to documentation for what members are available on what objects - and dealing with run-time error 438 whenever you make a typo, because late-bound code will happily compile and only be resolved at run-time.

Adding a reference to the CorelDRAW type library will allow you to write *early-bound* code that resolves at compile-time, exactly like the function calls you're making against the `VBA` or `Excel` type libraries, which are referenced by default in an Excel VBA project.

Comment: I was attempting to work around linking them manually because the goal of this macro was to decrease and simplify user interface. If I link it to CorelDraw, will the link stay active if I send the document to another computer with CorelDraw installed? If so this would make my code much easier and defeats any reason to attempt to work around it.

Comment: @JonnyKriefall It will surely work if you have the same version of CorelDraw on another computer. (Maybe it will work on different versions too, I don't know how CorelDraw version its library :))

Comment: @JonnyKriefall if the same version of CorelDRAW is installed on every machine that runs your code, there's nothing to worry about. If not, make sure you're referencing the earliest version any user can use, and there *shouldn't* be any problems. Same with the Scripting runtime and any other library you could possibly reference.

Comment: Thank you @Mat'sMug and @velblúd! You both have been extremely helpful